# Reading a string from Firebase and storing it as a CString

Tags: esp8266, string, iot, c-string

I have a mobile app (done using MIT App Inventor) storing some values to a Firebase database. App inventor stores all the values as strings (i.e. with quotes, and strings have quotes enclosed within quotes eg. `"\"hello\""`).

I'm using [this](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266) library to fetch data from Firebase to ESP8266. I'm using `String` var to store the value retrieved and then change it to a CString (trying to store it directly doesn't work) as below:

This doesn't work:

```cpp
Firebase.get(firebaseData, "/SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE1/FREQ FR");
Serial.print("node -- schedule1 /FREQ FR -- type: ");   
Serial.println(firebaseData.dataType());
char * cstr1 = new char [33];
cstr1 = firebaseData.stringData(); 
Serial.print(" -- data: ");
Serial.println(cstr1);
```

This works:

```cpp
Firebase.get(firebaseData, "/SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE1/WEIGHT");
Serial.print("node -- schedule1/WEIGHT -- type: ");   
Serial.println(firebaseData.dataType() ) ; 
String dummy = firebaseData.stringData();
Serial.print(" -- data: ");
Serial.print(dummy); 
char * cstr = new char [dummy.length()+1];
strcpy (cstr, dummy.c_str()); 
Serial.print(" -- data int type: ");
Serial.println(atoi(cstr)) ;
```

I have some more nodes to get data from and I've read that lots of `Strings` are a bad practice. While trying to find out more, I saw the source code and `stringData` function itself returns a CString:

[image]

I feel like I'm doing one step more than what is required! Any suggestions on how to go about this would be very useful!

**Try1** Based on the answer from @Majenko, I tried this before adding to the library:

```cpp
const char* get_cstring() {
  String str = "will it work" ; 
  return str.c_str();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  const char *new_c = get_cstring(); 
  int len = strlen(new_c);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Serial.println(new_c[i]);  
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("----------");
}
```

But how do I access the contents, because it just prints garbage values; `strlen(new_c)` gives 2 (I'm guessing that's the amount of storage needed in bytes!?)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the solution so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In returning a `String` object the Firebase first generates that `String` object and copies the C string data into it.

If you want to get at the raw C string data you will have to look at adding a new "getter" to the library to return the pointer to that C string data:

I'd write it for you, but since you posted a screenshot of the Firebase function, and the change from that code to the new code is very minor (just change the function name and the return type), I can't copy-and-paste it. And I'm not going to peer at that little image and type it all in again.

Incidentally, internally the Firebase library actually uses `std::string`, which is a better implementation of the same thing that `String` does. `String` was created because the Arduino compiler has no STL, and hence no `std::string`. Either way they both use dynamic allocation.

Comment: The problem you have is that your `str` variable is local to the function. It, and the memory allocated within it, gets destroyed when the function returns. So what you have in `new_c` is a pointer to nothing much. That shouldn't be the case with Firebase, since _data is a `std::string` that is a member variable, not a local variable.

Comment: I tried with a global `String` var ; it works! But when I try to use `new_c.atoi()` with an integer value as input, it fails; so how should the return type be declared!? or where should the change be made to perform those type conversions !?

Comment: @SomasundharamSampath Use `atoi(new_c)`

Comment: that was very stupid from me!!! Thanks a lot! Looks like I need another primer on C.